# Attribute that indicates is activerecord model in saving state?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to know if model is in saving state (between before_validate and after_save).

```
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save: do_before

  def do_before
    modelb.create(:attr => 123, :ref => self)
  end
end

class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create: do_before

  def do_before
    self.ref.my_attr = 321
    self.ref.save! unless self.ref.is_saving?
  end
end
```

I need "is_saving?" attribute for every model instance in my project. What is the best way to implement that?

Comment: Probably, creating base model class to be inherited by all models in system that inherits ActiveRecord::Base and declares is_saving attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you rather set an instance variable in between `:before_save` and `:after_save` by using ActiveRecord's `:around_save` callback and then yield your save? Anyway, the question is not too clear to me. What is the purpose of `is_saving?` method?

Comment: This is what I try to do: modela before_save creating record in modelb. In modelb before_create callback changing attribute of modela and if modela is_saving? it should not do modela.save! (in other case should do modela.save!)

Comment: I edited ruby code in question to illustrate better my last comment.